# "sqlsrv_query" static cursor type is slow

Tags: sqlsrv

I have found that using PHP to talk to a MSSQL database, we have incredibly slow results using sqlsrv_fetch_array(). Using sqlsrv_query and "Scrollable" => "static" allows us to iterate through a list of 600 items in 35 seconds, while buffered is completed in under 1 second.

Only one thing springs to mind - that this is a remote database on another server, and using a static cursor requires us to fetch a result directly from the database each time.

Or there's something fundamentally broken with these queries.

For reference, the application is in a Microsoft Azure App Service while the database is on a "SQL Instance" in Azure. However I get similar results when I run the app in debugging mode on my local PC.

I'm not too keen on changing things from "defaults".

What causes this issue and what's the fix? Or is to use a buffered cursor the right solution when dealing with lists of data over a remote connection?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm using a static cursor takes much longer and is subject to the workload on the SQL server.  For example using the static cursor the best time I could get when iterating a result set of almost 14,000 records is 14 seconds.  If we don't use the static cursor and go with the default we can iterate the same result set sometimes in less than a second.  And this is the BEST the static cursor could do.  We have examples of it taking 30s, 50s or even over a minute to pull all the rows from the SQL server.
There seems to be a major problem with the php drivers at least up to and including 17.8.1.1 with static cursors.
[result of command yum list installed msodbc*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofQ9w.png)

For the record this php is version:
PHP 7.3.23 (cli) (built: Sep 29 2020 08:33:03) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.23, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.3.23, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

running on CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)

Comment: That wouldn't be a driver bug. Static cursor causes SQL Server to insert the entire result set into the [tempdb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/tempdb-database) database, which means using more memory and more CPU.